# .NET Public Events not wiring up in nested web user controls

Tags: asp.net, events, public

I have C# Web Application that has an aspx page hosting a user control (Review.ascx). Inside that user control there are 5 more user controls, one of which has a public event (Review_Summary.ascx). The problem is no matter what i do I cannot get the event wired up in the parent ascx control (Review.ascx).

Here is what I have in the child control (Review_Summary.ascx)

```
    public event EventHandler forwardStatusChanged;

    #region methods

    protected void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnForward.Text == "Return")
        {
            if (forwardStatusChanged != null)
            {
                forwardStatusChanged(sender, e);
            }
            removeForward();
        }
    }
```

In the parent control (Review.ascx) I have this

```
   public void initReview(string EmployeeNumber)
    {
         RevSummary.forwardStatusChanged += new EventHandler(RevSummary_forwardStatusChanged);

          <more code here>
     }

 protected void RevSummary_forwardStatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblReadOnly.Visible = false;
        }
```

`RevSummary` is the ID of the child control in the parent control. `InitReveiw` is a method that is called by the aspx page in its Page_Load event.

I get no errors on compile or at runtime. But when I click the button the forwardStatusChanged event is null. The "removeForward()" method that is called after that executes properly. So that fact that the event is always null leads me to believe that the wire up in the parent control is not working. However, I am sure it is executing becasue all of the code after that executes.

How can I figure out why this event is not wiring up?

Comment: You need to bind up your events earlier in the page life cycle.  By the time they're bound, the event pipeline already determined there were no event handlers for the event.

Comment: At what point should I bind them? On Page_Init? Or Page_PreInit? Or where else?

Comment: I tried Init. PreInit is not available in User Controls. I also noticed that if I click the button twice the event fires correctly. So it requires two postbacks to work.

Comment: Try the init.  The fact that it works on 2nd post back makes me wonder if you have it somewhere inside of a:   if (IsPostBack){  // register event }

Answer (score 0):

Where is initReview being called from?  Are you sure it's being called because the only reason this happens is that the event handler wasn't truly setup.  I've never found a reason other than this, the several times I did this myself.

HTH.

Comment: It is being called from the aspx page. Yes, I am 100% positive that it is being called becasue other code after the wireup is executing.